# Setting property default values for a Web User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to build a web user control and set some default values for its properties in the code-behind like this:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(int), "50")]
public int Height { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(typeof(string), "string.Empty")]
public string FamilyName { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Orange")]
public System.Drawing.Color ForeColor { get; set; }
```

When I add the user control to the page and call it without any properties:

```
<uc1:Usercontrol ID="uc" runat="server" />
```

the default values are not set and every property is 0 or null.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `DefaultValueAttribute` will not set any value for your property, it only serves as a hint for designers and whatnot.

If you want a default value, you'll have to set it in the constructor (or even better, in a property initializer, which were added in C# 6). If you're storing your stuff in the ViewState, you'll need to expand those property definitions and make them access the ViewState. Then set the default values for the properties in the `OnInit` method to avoid persisting them on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx

Note 
A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

In other words, the DefaultValueAttribute just gives you a place to declare what you want the value to be.  You still have to write code to populate the value from the attribute.